# How to loop through a list of dictionaries with in a dictionary and get the values within - Javascript, for an ajax call in django

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a list

```
mylist =  [{"model": "todolist.todolist", "pk": 1, "fields": {"timezoneChoice": "Africa/Johannesburg", "user": 44, "name": "ergdsg", "discription": "dsgdsg", "dueMinutes": -61504892, "emailSent": false, "dueDate": "1899-12-11T08:20:00Z", "create_at": "2016-11-21T04:37:29.253Z"}}, {"model": "todolist.todolist", "pk": 2, "fields": {"timezoneChoice": "Africa/Johannesburg", "user": 44, "name": "ergdsg", "discription": "dsgdsg", "dueMinutes": -61504892, "emailSent": false, "dueDate": "1899-12-11T08:20:00Z", "create_at": "2016-11-21T04:38:12.525Z"}}]
```

I am trying to get the value from the "fields" and their keys

```
for (var i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++) {

                    $("#posts").prepend( "<div >" +"<h2 class='bg-info text-align-center'> Tasks" +"</h2>"
                                         + "<strong> Name: " + " "  + mylist[i].name + "</strong>"
                                         + "<strong> Task: " + " "  + mylist[i].discription + "</strong>"
                                         + "<strong> Due Date: " + " "  + mylist[i].dueDate + "</strong>"
                                         + "<strong> Mins before due: " + " "  + mylist[i].dueMinutes + "</strong>"
                                         + "<strong> TimeZone: " + " "  + mylist[i].timezoneChoice + "</strong>"
                                         + "<hr>" +"</div>")
                                },
```

How would I do this. Please I really need the help and have been struggling the whole day. I have read about javascript and dictionaries, but i cannot access the needed dictionary values in the loop. ? I would really appreciate if someone could give a code example.

Thank you

Comment: what is the error

Comment: @Mahi, i am just not getting a value , it says undefined

Comment: see jkong answer . it would work

Comment: @Mahi, the solution below does not work either... logically I cannot see why

Answer (score 1):

in you loops,just change mylist[i] to mylist[i][fields'],

```
for (var i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++) {

                $("#posts").prepend( "<div >" +"<h2 class='bg-info text-align-center'> Tasks" +"</h2>"
                                     + "<strong> Name: " + " "  + mylist[i]['fields'].name + "</strong>"
                                     + "<strong> Task: " + " "  + mylist[i]['fields'].discription + "</strong>"
                                     + "<strong> Due Date: " + " "  + mylist[i]['fields'].dueDate + "</strong>"
                                     + "<strong> Mins before due: " + " "  + mylist[i]['fields'].dueMinutes + "</strong>"
                                     + "<strong> TimeZone: " + " "  + mylist[i]['fields'].timezoneChoice + "</strong>"
                                     + "<hr>" +"</div>")
                            }
```

Comment: Hi I have tried that, it says it cannot read undefined... There is data in thr list I checked, just have no idea at this stage

Comment: @CuriousLambda do you check you list?you list's name is 'my list',there is a space between my & list,delete this space and try again

Comment: that is just in stack overflow, it is correct in my js file. This is serialised data from a django queryset which is being based to the js function... Thank you

Comment: i have try my code again it's correct,in you code for loop line 7 change json[i] to mylist[i]['fields']

Comment: Ok , so it was silly mistake on my part, before passing this to the Ajax function I serialized the query set and the placed this queryset in to json.dumps, this turned it in to a single string, so the solution was to serialize it and pass it directly to the ajax success function